# Display all HTML element values in the same HTML page without Page load using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML page with mulitple input:text, input:checkbox, input:select, etc., I would like to show the selected, textbox value and checkbox selected in the same page in a  without reloading the page.

If I change the textbox, the respective value in the div should be changed. Also if I de-select or empty the textbox value, the respective value in the  should be removed.

Can someone give me the page reference or source code for the same.

```
   <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="name1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Source</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="source" name="source">
                    <option>Just Dial</option>
                    <option>Web</option>
                    <option>Reference</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="name1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Name 1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="name1" name="name1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="name2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Name 2</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  id="name2" name="name2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="contact1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Contact #1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="contact1" name="contact1">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="contact2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Contact #2</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="contact2" name="contact2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="email1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Email 1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="email" required="required" class="form-control input-sm" id="email1" name="email1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="email2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Email 2</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="email2" name="email2">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I have the above HTML content, even more in a wizard format of 4 tabs. At the 4th tab I have the submit button to validate and store values in DB.

I would to to display in the same page that, what are all the fields I have entered value, checked checkboxes and selected dropdown in a . I can verify by seeing the content in before I click the submit button in 4th tab in the wizard to make sure I have the correct vales in textboxes, selected dropdowns and checked checkboxes. I want this to interactively display the content in the without reloading the page.

So I need the source code or reference URL, where I can get idea on implementing the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit you question and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Please share details? What's the page layout, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="name1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Source</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="source" name="source">
                        <option>Just Dial</option>
                        <option>Web</option>
                        <option>Reference</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="name1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Name 1</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="name1" name="name1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="name2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Name 2</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  id="name2" name="name2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="contact1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Contact #1</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="contact1" name="contact1">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="contact2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Contact #2</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="contact2" name="contact2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="email1" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Email 1</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="email" required="required" class="form-control input-sm" id="email1" name="email1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label for="email2" class="formlabel control-label col-xs-3">Email 2</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="email2" name="email2">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I have the above HTML content, even more in a wizard format of 4 tabs. At the 4th tab I have the submit button to validate and store values in DB.

I would to to display in the same page that, what are all the fields I have entered value, checked checkboxes and selected dropdown in a `<div>`. I can verify by seeing the content in `<div>` before I click the submit button in 4th tab in the wizard to make sure I have the correct vales in textboxes, selected dropdowns and checked checkboxes. I want this to interactively display the content in the `<div>` without reloading the page.

So I need the source code or reference URL, where I can get idea on implementing the same.